# .htaccess r=301 vs r=302

Tags: http, .htaccess, redirect, http-headers

I am creating rules in my .htaccess for mobile, or bad pages etc...

I am using these rules:

```
rewriterules badpage /goodpage.html [r=302]

rewriterules iphone /iphone.html [r=301]
```

Which one is better to use?

I know is temporary and permanent, but when a temporary becomes permanent, my understanding is both do the same thing so same result at the end.

I would like to know what is the difference between the 301 and 302 on a browser and bots perspective.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When permanently moving a web site, or a web page, best practice is to use a 301 redirect. 302s in this situation seem incorrect. By saying "temporary move" a 302 tells search engines to keep the old domain or page indexed, but it would be desireable for them to index the new location. People use 302 redirects in an effort to circumvent the Google aging delay. This workaround might have worked at some point, but it is not a current best practice.

Ref: [301 Vs 302 Redirects](http://blog.webhosting.uk.com/web-hosting/301-vs-302-redirect/)