# .htaccess Redirect URL to a New one page

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a url to a new one, at the same site!

The old url:

```
 index.php?route=product%2Fproduct&path=63_64_83&product_id=163&pk_campaign=Facebook_Ads&pk_kwd=Alum_i5
```

The new url:

```
 http://bit.ly/19xN3Pv
```

The `Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product%2Fproduct&path=63_64_83&product_id=163&pk_campaign=Facebook_Ads&pk_kwd=Alum_i5 http://bit.ly/19xN3Pv`,

doesn't work!
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**[edit]** This should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} route=product%2Fproduct&path=63_64_83&product_id=163&pk_campaign=Facebook_Ads&pk_kwd=Alum_i5
RewriteRule ^index.php.*$    http://bit.ly/19xN3Pv [R=301,L]
```

Comment: should add a description of the `R=301` flag

Comment: 301 = permanent redirect. 302 = temporary. more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700621/htaccess-r-301-vs-r-302

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product\%2Fproduct&path=63_64_83&product_id=163&pk_campaign=Facebook_Ads&pk_kwd=Alum_i5$
RewriteRule ^inedx\.php$ http://bit.ly/19xN3Pv [L,NC,R=301]
```